# Xamarin.Android: Implement Zoom use-case using Camera2 > Multi-camera API

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-camera2, multi-camera-api, wide-angle

I have tried to implement a Multi-camera API to access a Wide-angle camera but no luck. Using the following links, not getting camera Ids on Nokia 7.2, Mi A1, Mi A3, One Plus Nord 2, and  Samsung M30s.

- https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/fu3nSnk7Ox0
- [On Android - how to capture image/video from the wide angle camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590411/on-android-how-to-capture-image-video-from-the-wide-angle-camera)

Also, I tried to convert Java source code to Xamarin.Android from listed links but some constants are not found in Xamarin.Android (CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA, CameraCharacteristics.REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE).

- https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multi-camera
- [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice

Kindly provide some documentation/guidance to achieve this or suggest any library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/pie):

To determine if the device supports a logical multi camera, you can look at the capabilities of each camera on the device to see if it supports [RequestAvailableCapabilitiesLogicalMultiCamera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA).

Android Pie also includes a new [SessionConfiguration class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/SessionConfiguration.html) that can be used to help reduce delays during initial capture and eliminate the need to start and start the camera stream.

For more information about Multi-Camera support in Android P, see [Multi-camera support and camera updates.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#camera)